# How to use ajax call to pass json data to controller and render a partial view as result?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass model object to controller, and from there to call service to generate data for the partial view.  I am able to pass the json object to the main view, and I am able to generate the partial view.  However, I am having difficulties to render the partial view in the main view after the call. If I don't pass object to controller, I am able to render the partial view.

**My Main goal is: to pass json object and render partial view with the same ajax call.**

**Would appreciate help on this.**

*I apologize for the lengthy code here, but not sure how I could do it some other way.*

The following code works, where I do not pass Json object via ajax call, and create department object in the controller:

main view code:

```
@model PartialViewDemo.Models.School
....
<body>
    ....
    <div>
        @Html.Partial("_MyPartialView", Model.Department )
    </div>
    ....
    <div id="divTest"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="btnClick"/>
</body>

<script src="~/Content/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#btnClick').click(function(data) {
            var dept = {
                DepartmentName: "test Dept",
                DepartmentRule: "test rule",
                Comment:" test comment"
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/ShowPartailView/',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divTest').html(result);
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

controller code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new School();
    model.Department = GetDepartmentList(3);
    return View(model);
}

public List<Department> GetDepartmentList(int counter)
{
    var model = new List<Department>();
    for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i++)
    {
        var data = new Department();
        data.DepartmentName = "Dept " + i;
        data.DepartmentRule = "Rule " + i;
        data.Comment = "Comment " + i;
        model.Add(data);
    }
    return model;
}

public PartialViewResult ShowPartailView()
{
    Department dept = new Department()
    {
        DepartmentName = "test Dept",
        DepartmentRule = "test rule",
        Comment = "We Rock!"
    };
    PartialViewResult result = PartialView("_MySecondPartialView", dept);
    return result;
}
```

Partial view code:

```
@model PartialViewDemo.Models.Department
<h2>_MyView from partial view using PartialView</h2>
@if (Model != null)
{
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                ....
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.DepartmentName</td>
                    <td>@Model.DepartmentRule</td>
                    <td>@Model.Comment</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Model:

```
public class Department
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentRule { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public List<Department>  Department { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I pass in Json object to ajax call with all other code stay the same, except the following changes, the partial view won't show with click event.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/ShowPartailView/',
    data: JSON.stringify(dept),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#divTest').html(result);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

with controller code:

```
public PartialViewResult ShowPartailView(Department dept)
{
    PartialViewResult result = PartialView("_MySecondPartialView", dept);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show you code! What have you tried?

Comment: Just updated with code and result.

Comment: You can just use `data: dept,` and delete the `contentType: ...` option

Comment: Tried that, still no cigar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example where you pass the object, you have specified the

```
dataType: 'json',
```

ajax option but your controller method is returning a partial view so it needs to be

```
dataType: 'html',
```

Side note: You can omit the `contentType` option and just use `data: dept,`

Comment: Thank you, That worked!  So  the dataType in the ajax call is for the response, and not for the  request, right?

Comment: Yes, contentType is what your send to the controller and dataType is what you get back

Answer (score 0):

If you have return partial view then try this to render partial view in Div or any other element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/YourContollerName/YourActionName',
        type: "POST"
    })
    .success(function (result) {
     $('.loadOnDivClass').empty();
     $('.loadOnDivClass').html(result);
 })
  .error(function (status) {
      alert(status);
  })

});
```

If Contrller Action return like this

return PartialView("_PartialList",modelObj);

Comment: This is not what I want. please see my edit above. I wanted to pass json object and render partial view with the same ajax call. which I am not able to accomplish that